# Android HID USB how to send hexadecimal data with bulkTransfer or controlTransfer?

Tags: java, android, usb, hid

I'm trying to send hexadecimal data to connected USB HID device from my Nexus 7, but Android SDK method can work only with byte[] buffer.

How can I send hexadeсimal data that originates as decimal String values with bulkTransfer or controlTransfer?

```
message[0]= 0;
message[1]= 166;
message[2]= 2;
message[3]= 252;
message[4]= 255;
```

SDK Methods:

```
bulkTransfer(UsbEndpoint endpoint, byte[] buffer, int length, int timeout)

controlTransfer(int requestType, int request, int value, int index, byte[] buffer, int length, int timeout)
```

like this:
http://pure-basic.narod.ru/article/pickit2.html, PC application with the device works good.

```
OutBuffer(0)=0
OutBuffer(1)=$A6 ; EXECUTE_SCRIPT
OutBuffer(2)=2
OutBuffer(3)=$FC ; _VDD_GND_OFF
OutBuffer(4)=$FF ; _VDD_ON
```

**UPDATE - ANSWER**

```
private void sendData() {
  //byte b = (byte) 129; // (byte) 0x81 Also work
  int status = connection.bulkTransfer(endPointWrite, toByte(129), 1, 250);
}

private static byte toByte(int c) {
  return (byte) (c <= 0x7f ? c : ((c % 0x80) - 0x80));
}

// for received data from USB HID device
private static int toInt(byte b) {
  return (int) b & 0xFF;
}
```

**[My application on Google play - USB HID TERMINAL](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.usbhidterminal)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what the target of the `message` buffer will be.

Since you are getting decimal values from a String you can use the `Integer.parseInt` method with a radix of 10, then cast to a `byte`:

```
byte message[] = new byte[] { (byte)java.lang.Integer.parseInt("0", 10),
            (byte)java.lang.Integer.parseInt("166", 10),
            (byte)java.lang.Integer.parseInt("2", 10),
            (byte)java.lang.Integer.parseInt("252", 10),
            (byte)java.lang.Integer.parseInt("255", 10)
};
```

If you simply want to send the data over the bulk pipe then you would send it as follows:

```
bulkTransfer(outEndpoint, message, message.length, 1000);
```

Control requests typically target some function on the USB device itself and is vendor defined. If you need to send the buffer as a control request you would send it as follows:

```
controlTransfer(USB_DIR_OUT, VENDOR_DEFINED_REQUEST, VENDOR_DEFINED_VALUE, USB_INTERFACE_INDEX, message, message.length, 1000);
```

Comment: thanks, but your and this code not work: byte message[] = new byte[] {3, 100, 127, **128**, **256**}; byte in Java: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of **-128** and a maximum value of **127** (inclusive).

Comment: this code work: message = new byte[] {(byte) 0x80}; but I trying to convert data from String with Byte.parseByte(str[i]); or Byte.decode(str[i]), and I have NFE when I use data > than 127. Also, new byte[] {(byte) 128}; work.

Comment: I just revised my answer and added the missing information that the decimal values are originating from a String to your question. Sorry thought this was C originally, the revised answer contains the java code.